# flask python internal logger not printing to log or console

Tags: python-3.x, flask, logging

I running flask app and i have an internal error in :
C:\Python36-64\Lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\csrf.py

```
 except ValidationError as e:
            logger.info(e.args[0])
            raise
```

the problem is that i can't see this logger.info anywhere .. 
in my flask app i defined the logger as this :

```
logger = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logsdir = 'logs/'
handler = RotatingFileHandler(logsdir + "log.log")
# Create Error handler
error_handler = RotatingFileHandler(logsdir + "error_logger.log")
error_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.addHandler(error_handler)
logger.addHandler(default_handler)
app.logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably move this to hook in Flask. You can also look at global exception handling in Flask: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/. 
Below is a code to configure the logger before the request.

```py
@app.before_first_request
def setup_logging():
    if not app.debug:
        # In production mode, add log handler to sys.stdout.
        app.logger.handlers.pop()
        if not app.logger.hasHandlers():
            handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
            handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
                '%(asctime)s - [%(levelname)s] - [%(thread)d] - [%(threadName)s] - %(name)s  - %(message)s'))
            app.logger.addHandler(handler)
            app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            app.logger.propagate = False
            app.logger.propagate = False
            app.logger.handler_set = True
        return app.logger
```

Global exception handler, example from Flask document.

```py
from flask import json
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

@app.errorhandler(HTTPException)
def handle_exception(e):
    """Return JSON instead of HTML for HTTP errors."""
    # start with the correct headers and status code from the error
    response = e.get_response()
    # replace the body with JSON
    response.data = json.dumps({
        "code": e.code,
        "name": e.name,
        "description": e.description,
    })
    response.content_type = "application/json"
    return response
```

Additionally. look at traceback for some more trace information:

```py
        try:
           return fetch_some_from_db(), 200
        except NoResultFound as ex:
            LOGGER.error("Received exception in DeleteResource: {}".format(ex))
            traceback.print_exc()
            db.session.rollback()
            db.session.close()
            # handle_failure(interface, message, message_json)
            return DEFAULT_FAILURE_MESSAGE_NO_MAPPING, 400
```

Comment: i guess you can start with @app.before_first_request and see.